# would someone explain how to get the notebook list into a listbox

Tags: vb.net, evernote

```
 ' Get a list of all notebooks in the user's account.
    Dim myNotebookList As List(Of ENNotebook) = ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks()

    For Each item In myNotebookList
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
```

all this gives me is a list of the following line...
Evernote SDK ENNotebook

how do i get the names of my notebooks to display in the listbox.
Using VS2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation of the Notebook Object : https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_Notebook

As you can see, there's a 'name' property that will give you the name of the notebook.

So your code should be something like :

```html
' Get a list of all notebooks in the user's account.
    Dim myNotebookList As List(Of ENNotebook) = ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks()

    For Each item In myNotebookList
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item.name)
    Next
```